# onActivityResult in Activity not called after startActivityForResult from Fragment in API 18

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I want the user to select a picture from his gallery, therefore I have the following.

I have a SettingsActivity where it says:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        //do sth here
    }
}
```

In the onCreateMethod of this SettingsActivity i do:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

And then I have the SettingsFragment which does the following in the onCreate()

```
Preference pref = (Preference) findPreference(SettingsConstants.Key.PREF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE);
    pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SettingsActivity.RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This worked in 4.2 - but is not working with 4.3 anymore! Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here, or is anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Fragmenst have an [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) too, does the code return there?

Comment: The code does also not return in the Fragments onActivityResult() method

Comment: Just to be sure, the intent chooser and chosen intent work like before, only the onActivityResult isn't called?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @kevinhoo I do not get any error. The onActivityResult() method is simply not called

Answer (score 0):

It is called, but the request code u set in fragment is different in the parameter of your
`onActivityResult` activity's method!

Comment: I dont see how you think this are different request codes? The RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE is defined in the SettingsActivity as static public member and used in startActivityForResult method in the Fragment.

Comment: That's true, you pass this code into `startActivityForResult(intent, code)` method. But when your `onActivityResult(codeDifferent, resultCode, intent)` is called back, the code is not the one you have passed. This is because internally it's transformed for activity and for fragment. @X.X_Mass_Developer

Comment: I do not believe that to code is changed internally, do you have any reference for your statement?
However, the method onActivityResult() is not even called!

Comment: `if ((requestCode&0xffff0000) != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode");
        }
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, ((fragment.mIndex+1)<<16) + (requestCode&0xffff));`

Comment: It's from Activity source codes. But in fact only in the compat library. So your suggestion was some right.